# Java Programing Project

Tags: java

I am working on this java project, but I cant get it to run properly. I keep getting an error. I think it might be something to due with my Rectangle driver, but I'm not sure. can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Update*: I originally was getting an error code that said: " The method main cannot be declared static: static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type"
It gave me 2 options to fix this,  could either remove the static modifier from main, or I could add static to the parent type. when I chose the option of removing static from main, it came bac with: "error main method is not static, please define main method as static" So I decided to go with the second option and add the static modifier to the parent type. once I did that I started getting

this error:
"No enclosing instance of type Project6 is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type
Project6 (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Project6)."

*Update: Okay as many of you suggested I have removed all of the extra public classes from my code. my new code is below, I am now getting an error code that says:
"Main.java:1: error: class RectangleDriver is public, should be declared in a file named RectangleDriver.java
public class RectangleDriver"

New Code:

```
public class RectangleDriver
{
public static void main(String[] args) {

Rectangle obj=new Rectangle();
int length=10,width=10;

obj.setLength(length);
obj.setWidth(width);

if(obj.isSquare())
{
   System.out.println("Square: "+obj.getLength()+"x"+obj.getWidth());
 }
 else
 {
   System.out.println("Rectangle: "+obj.getLength()+"x"+obj.getWidth());
}

}
}
class Rectangle{
private int length;
private int width;
  
public void setLength(int length){
this.length=length;
}

public void setWidth(int width){
this.width=width;
}
  
public int getLength()
{
return length;
}
  
public int getWidth()
{
return width;
}
  
public boolean isSquare()
{
if(length==width)
return true;
  
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: What is the error exactly?  What line does it occur?  Can you add the full text of the error message?

Comment: And how do you try to start it?

Comment: Are these classes literally in the same file or did you just post them like that?

Comment: "I keep getting an error" is not enough specific for others facing same problem to find this question along with potential answers, which is *whole point of this site*. So please [edit] your question and include error message along with description of what you are trying to achieve with this code.

Comment: Also please indent your code properly. *DON'T* do it manually since humans tend to make mistakes. Let your editor do it for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As others have suggested, you can have as many classes/interfaces inside your .java file but only one class can be public and it should match with the name of the file. I have removed the reference of public class Project6 { } Not sure why it was needed.

```
public class RectangleDriver
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   Rectangle obj=new Rectangle();
   int length=10,width=10;

   obj.setLength(length);
   obj.setWidth(width);
  
   if(obj.isSquare())
   {
       System.out.println("Square: "+obj.getLength()+"x"+obj.getWidth());
   }
   else
   {
       System.out.println("Rectangle: "+obj.getLength()+"x"+obj.getWidth());
   }
  
   }
}
 class Rectangle{
    private int length;
    private int width;
      
    public void setLength(int length){
    this.length=length;
    }
    
    public void setWidth(int width){
    this.width=width;
    }
      
    public int getLength()
    {
    return length;
    }
      
    public int getWidth()
    {
    return width;
    }
      
    public boolean isSquare()
    {
    if(length==width)
    return true;
      
    return false;
    }
    }
```

Comment: @dunni please explain your logic....we also want to know

Comment: Amit it wasn't me. your answer was actually very helpful. also, now that i have done what you show, am am getting an erro code that says: "Main.java:1: error: class RectangleDriver is public, should be declared in a file named RectangleDriver.java
public class RectangleDriver"

Comment: @AmimulEhsanRahi i downvoted the first version of your answer, because it was simply not fitting to this question and confusing. I didn't downvote this one.

Comment: But technically this answer is also only showing a workaround and doesn't answer, why the OP got the error in the first place (which is, that non-static inner classes cannot have static methods)

Comment: Okay. I have updated my post to include all the error codes, and what i have done so far.

Comment: @ErikKeener save my code in a file RectangleDriver.java and run it. If you are able to run it then please accept the answer and give a upvote. Let me know i am available to help you.

Comment: @dunni Have patient before downvoting. I tried to fix the Program and provided an explanation. If you paid attention to the question you may see that the Class construction itself was not correct. There were multiple public class and then class was decleared inside a class. So i fixed the code and provided a running code.

Comment: @dunni thanks for your concern....got it.........

Comment: @Amit there was a misconception........... I first answered with the same but with some language error. That's why he downvoted me......And He said that he hasn't downvoted you. Your code is working well.

Comment: @ErikKeener I think you should use a good IDE. Then a lot of suggestions will come on the way. The most popular java IDE is  Intellij Idea. Use this IDE and your life as a programmer will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

Since you declared the static main method in an inner class, you also have to define that inner class as static, i.e.:

```
public static class RectangleDriver {}
```

Alternatively, move the RectangleDriver class into its own file and make it a proper top level class.